# Can I use an existing Hibernate SessionFactory to reinitialize my database schema?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'd like to provide the ability to completely wipe my webapp's database from its GUI, rebuilding the tables with the auto-generated DDL gleaned from an `AnnotationConfiguration`.

At the moment I do this by programatically setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create` and then creating a new SessionFactory.

```
AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
if (nukeDB)
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
for (Class<?> clas : HibernateMappedClasses) {
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(clas);
}
return cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

but this requires creating a fresh `AnnotationConfiguration` from the one that Spring is building for the rest of the app.

Can I use my existing `SessionFactory` to recreate the database schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't simple in raw Hibernate, but given that I'm using Spring, it turns out that the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` has methods `dropDatabaseSchema` and `createDatabaseSchema` that together do the trick.

Without Spring I think I'd copy the code in those methods!